# Gauged supergravity

Tags: supergravity, gauge

It is said that in N=2 supergravity coupled to vector multiplets and hypermultiplets, one can gauge the R-symmetry by equivalently gauging the isometries of the corresponding hyperkahler cone over the quaternionic Kahler target manifold of the hypermultiplets (see e.g. 2nd paragraph of http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0104215.pdf).

I would like to be able to see explicitly why gauging these isometries is equivalent to gauging the R symmetry. I cannot find this explained in any papers/books (at least not at a level that I can understand it!)

Can anybody offer an explanation?

Thanks.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): In the future please link to abstract pages rather than pdf files, e.g.,  http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0104215

Comment: Please see [our guide](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6413/how-do-we-write-good-question-titles) on writing good titles.